# Site Users Web Part for SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

I am aware of "Site Users Web Part" with SharePoint On Perm version as mention in below link

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/site-users-web-part-32c2cc3e-b1c7-4eb3-8832-0fc3ab321297

What I am looking for is a replacement in SharePoint Online to displays list of users and groups who have permission to use a site.

I know that SharePoint online has two types of site Classic/Modern and I am looking for an option of a Modern site.

EDIT:

Based on the answer I tried to use People Web part to see if the approach works but it did not work for me.

[image]

Comment: HOnestly, this is what always kills Sharepoint. Such a basic thing. We would like to have a table of group members displayed with email addresses because in our institution we have other departments for which this would provide an easy way to validate simple things about our staff as a group. jeepers!

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the answer to my own question. When I logged in to the Modern site I see total number of the members who have access to the site on the top right corner below following link. When I click on members link I see complete details which is what I feel replacing Site User Web Part. Please feel free to comment.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How about Sharepoint Group. If we need to show users from particular group?

Comment: You can see group level permission by clicking on Gear Icon(Top right) -> Site Permissions

Comment: This method only shows the Groups for me. I need to see the users in the Site Members group. Eventually, I need to see the users in the Active Directory group.

Answer (score -2):

Yes we already have a people part for de Modern Experience.
Check out include this new feature on a page (obviosuly in a Modern mode), i think it's called "People" for US tenants. There isn't exatly a full user's profile card like SharePoint Server did in a convencional web part, but Works!

Also, you can choose between Compact or Descript layout.
FYI [image]

Comment: This web part doesn't give me a list of users who have access to the site. when I added this web part it gives me a text box where I can add multiple users and then it shows me the similar interface that you shared. Let me know if I am missing something.